# Unable to retrieve the hidden element in partial view from main view

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have implemented kendo combobox on my MVC5 view and want the combobox to be filtered based on the value in my model. I need to retrieve the value from my model. I have currently bound that value to a hidden field called CountryCode in my partial view. The script is in my main view. I am getting error message undefined while trying to access the hidden field. The model is definitely getting populated with the CountryCode.

```
 @using System.Collections
@model CC.GRP.MCRequest.ViewModels.RequestStatusUpdateViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

 <div class="k-popup-edit-form k-window-content k-content" >
        <div class="k-edit-form-container">
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CountryCode)
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestID)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } })
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } })
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestStatus)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.RequestStatusCode)

                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                    .DataTextField("Status")
                    .Placeholder("Select...")
                    .DataValueField("RequestStatusCode")
                    .AutoBind(false)
                    .Filter("contains")

                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource

                    .Read(read =>
                    {
                        read.Action("GetRequestStatus", "Request")
                            .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
                            .Data("GetCountryCodeFilter");
                    }).ServerFiltering(true)


                       )
                    )
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestStatusCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>

    </div>
```

**Controller method that populates the combo**

```
 public ActionResult GetRequestStatus(string countryCode)
        {
            var response = requestRepository.GetRequestStatus(countryCode).AsQueryable().ProjectTo<RequestStatusViewModel>();

            var jsonResult = Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return jsonResult;
        }
```

**Controller method that loads the view**

```
public ActionResult RequestStatus(int requestId, string projectName, string countryCode)
    {
        RequestStatusUpdateViewModel reqeustStatusUpdateViewModel = new RequestStatusUpdateViewModel();

        reqeustStatusUpdateViewModel.RequestID = requestId;
        reqeustStatusUpdateViewModel.ProjectName = projectName;
        reqeustStatusUpdateViewModel.CountryCode = countryCode;

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // return View("NewRequestView", Mapper.Map<RequestStatusViewModel>(newReqeustViewModel));
            return null;
        }
        return View("_RequestStatusView", Mapper.Map<RequestStatusUpdateViewModel>(reqeustStatusUpdateViewModel));
    }
```

**RequestStatusViewModel**

```
  public class RequestStatusViewModel
        {
            public string RequestStatusCode { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public int DisplaySequenceNo { get; set; }
        }
```

**Script in the main view**

```
function GetCountryCodeFilter() {
        alert("Hello");
        alert($('#CountryCode').val());

        return { countryCode: $('#CountryCode').val() }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a popup from a kendo grid. The problem is that view gets serialized and sent to the popup when any row is clicked. It doesn't bind the data like you expect in MVC - it sends the same serialized data every time. See [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/layout/window/how-to/MVVM/mvvm-editing-form).

So change your hidden to use kendo's MVVM binding so each instance gets the value from the grid row. (CountryCode needs to exist in the grid's datasource):

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CountryCode, new { data_bind = "value: CountryCode" })  // underscore becomes dash
```

Or you could just use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="CountryCode" id="CountryCode" data-bind = "value: CountryCode"/>
```